# How to convert an Excel spreadsheet to a CSV file in React?

Tags: reactjs, csv, amazon-s3, file-conversion

I'm creating a file upload system in my React app that allows users to upload an Excel spreadsheet to an S3 bucket which can then be converted to a CSV.

```
const submitFile = (substring) => {
  const ReactS3Client = new S3(config);
  ReactS3Client.uploadFile(file, substring).then(data => {
    if (data.status === 204) {
      alert("File successfully uploaded");
    } else {
      alert("Something went wrong");
    }
  })
};
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to take the Excel spreadsheet file and convert it to a CSV file before I upload it to the S3 bucket. I haven't been able to find much about this so I'm not sure if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the npm package, [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx), may have a utility for doing just that.

Take a look at the `XLSX.utils.sheet_to_csv` util.